# Plenty of similarities isn’t it.? Or Plenty of similarities aren't it? Which expression is correct

Tags: singular-vs-plural, existentials, tag-questions

Plenty of similarities isn’t it.? Or Plenty of similarities aren't it? Which expression is correct when we are comparing & referring to some 20 or more pictures?

Comment: Those are both wrong, aren't they?

Comment: @tchrist More precise witticisms available, aren't there?

Comment: 'Similarities' is a plural word, so it's "[There are] plenty of similarities, aren't there?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting this should be an answer,

Answer (score 1):

The declarative form is "There are plenty of similarities.", so the question you want is "Plenty of similarities, aren't there?"